# CSS class precedence

Tags: css

I have two classes, one is used specifically fro certain  tags, the other can be used on any tag:

```
a.action_link_2 {
    display:inline-block;
}

.display_none {
    display:none;
}
```

In some circumstances I want to apply both these styles and have tried this:

```
<a class="action_link display_none">content</a>
```

However, when rendered in the browser, the 'action_link' class take precedence. I understand that this might be to do with CSS class priority, i.e. tag-specific classes taking precedence. My question is how do I make this tag hidden using these classes and still allow the 'display_none' class to be used on any element to hide it?

Comment: [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just remove the `a` from before the class, and also add body before the display none class to give it a higher priority.

```
.action_link_2 {
    display:inline-block;
}

body .display_none {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it because specificity read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

> To overcome the problem, you need to increase the specificity for
>   `.display_none` class when it is present on action_link_2 .

Just add one more rule, just below all of it

```
a.display_none {
        display:none;
    }
```

> This will work , but there will be a problem when you try to add class
>   `.display_none` to an `anchor`, but there is no `.action_link_2` class
>   present.

So the final and best solution would be to use:

```
.action_link_2.display_none {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem favorable because I don't want to have to add '.display_none' variation to every other class definition. The '.display_none' class should be able to be used anywhere. I suspect the answer posted by Aaron above is more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
.display_none { display:none !important; }
```

Comment: People have suggested that using !important is poly-fill (?) and trying to avoid it is first priority.

Comment: [Sounds good to me](https://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill) as it still looks the simpler / efficient way to do in your case...

Comment: See the above CSS specificy link for confirmation of bad practice.

Comment: I understand your point of view. However keep in mind that it exists and is valid css, also used in well reputed frameworks like Bootstrap